# Is there a SubImageApply?

Tags: image-processing, image

Given an image and a subimage (as a rectangle or pixel ranges):

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
f = FindFaces[img]; HighlightImage[img, f]
```

[image]

How would one apply operations just that sub-image, leaving the rest of the pixels unchanged?

```
(* would maybe be something like this *)
ImageConvolve[img, BoxMatrix[1]/11, "MapAt" -> f]
ImageApply[Max, img, "Subimage" -> f]
```

[image]

Is there a built-in or slick way to this (without resorting to `ImageData` and `MapAt`)? I thought there was something like this added in 12, but was perhaps mistaken.  If not, `ImageMapAt` or `ImageApplyAt` or some such thing would surely make a nice repository function.

Comment: For that matter, doesn't look like `FindFaces` returns index slices, only less useful rectangles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `f` matches `{__Rectangle}`:

```
subImageApply[image_Image, sub : {__Rectangle}, filter_] := Fold[
  ImageCompose[#, #2[[1]], #2[[2]], {0, 0}] &
, image
, { filter @ ImageTrim[image, #],  #[[1]] } & /@ sub
]

subImageApply[img, f, Blur[#, 12] &]
```

[image]

You can use ImageConvolve or whatever you need instead of `Blur`.

`Fold` is there to account for multiple rectangles.

Comment: Elegant! Thanks :)  I think if they just added "Masking" option to every image operation that would be super

Comment: @M.R. You are welcome. I expected it to be easier but that is fine enough I guess. Otoh image-processing is not my area so maybe I missed something.

Comment: `ImageApply` and `ImageFilter` take `Masking` option.